# While Installing the Phone gap 1.4.1.dmg Inside the MAC M/C getting the Error

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I have Mac mini machine It has 10.3.9 Mac OS. Now I want to develop the Iphone application on that. I have downloaded Xcode 1.5 from apple side. I have Install the Xcode and simple "hello woeld" is running properly.

Now I want to use phonegap to create Iphone application. I have downloaded the phonegap.dmg from below [link](http://phonegap.com/start). but when I am trying to install I am getting the warrning that *The following image disk images failes to mount and phonegap -1.4.1.dmg no mountable file System* all this error can come in this window.

**My concern is that I am using very Old OS for that I am using is some other version or is their any problem with the OS.**

Comment: Why do not you upgrade your OS?

Comment: I have updated my OS . It is 10.3.3 to 10.3.9. In left side corner their is one Apple sign from their I have updated the S/W. In that what ever S/W update available for me I have used all. And it is updated automatically. Is their any other way can we update software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel-based computer with Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6).
It is clearly mentioned in phone gap website .So you have to upgrade your system.

Comment: can you please tell me how update the Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6).

Comment: You will need a new computer. Your current computer is a PowerPC-based Mac Mini, and as such cannot run Mac OS X 10.6.